# Android HttpURLConnection disconnect not closing

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection to connect to server.And i want to cancel the connection by disconnecting the connection using conn.disconnect.But the connection is not getting cancelled.

Comment: Try `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");`

Comment: Add your code for clarification.